# Scroll bug in ie7 and ie9 when using css3pie gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar, css3pie

i use css3pie for my page to use css3 effects in the ie browsers.

Everything works fine. But now i have a field on my page that has a horizintal scrollbar.

In ie8 everything works finde. But in ie7 i cant scroll dragging the scrollbar. I can only use the arrows on the left and right.

and in ie9 i cant scroll.. i also cant drag the scrollbar. but if i click on the arrows on the left and right the scrolling element directly jumps  to the left back..

i use pie v1.0beta5

i found that issue on many sites but there was no solution that works for me..

i have a wrapper arount my page that has a linear gradient background.. if i remove that everything works fine.. but with the gradient background i cant scroll in ie7 and ie9..

does anyone have the same problem and maybe found a solution for this problem?

Comment: This is your issue? https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/190

Comment: yeah thats my issue.. but "-pie-track-active:false" dont work in my ie7.. in ie7 i can scroll using the buttons on the left and right in the scrollbar.. but in ie9 can`t even use this.. the scrollbar direktly jumps back to the left if i want to scroll

Comment: Did you build from source? As it says in that ticket the -pie-track-active feature is not yet in the released version.

Comment: @lojjic: I read the PIE issues and this question and am unsure where to add the -pie-track-active.  I have an inline-block that has an auto overflow-y.  When the scrollbar comes up in IE, the only way to drag the scrollblock is to double click it.  Adding the fix to the element didn't seem to help.  Perhaps I should ask this as a new question.  Also, this element has no PIE behaviors attached to it (that I am aware of)

Comment: @lojjic: nevermind, it seems you have to add the `-pie-track-active:false` to all ancestor elements that use a PIE behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nevermind, it seems you have to add the -pie-track-active:false to all ancestor elements that use a PIE behavior