# GWT ListBox Scrollbar in IE7 not dragging - need to double click Scrollbar to drag

Tags: gwt, css, scrollbar

i can press the up/down arrows (holding them doesn't work - only goes down once) - and clicking and dragging the scrollbar does not work. double clicking the scrollbar and then dragging seems to work.

note - this works fine for Chrome and IE8 - but we have to support IE7.

I've seen other posts on stackoverflow similar to this but all the fixes weren't applicable - for instance this post: [Scroll bug in ie7 and ie9 when using css3pie gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531224/scroll-bug-in-ie7-and-ie9-when-using-css3pie-gradient) - is exactly the same bug.  mine's just happening with GWT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated